# Google play services doesnt displays leaderboard after Auth

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, leaderboard

Its a very weird have invested a lot of time in this. So asking here.

I am using this plugin and followed the steps https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

I just want to use Google play services in release mode for leaderboard only (i am using in alpha launch)

Here is my code for Auth in GPlay services :

```
void Awake(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GameOverCount",0);

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    Authenticate ();
    #endif}
```

I have configured Gplay setup by providing 10+ digit Client ID

I have generated OAuth Client ID from Google APis using SHA1 of release.keystore that i am using. 
In Gplay service in DEveloper console : I have published the linked apps without any errors

```
public void Authenticate() {
    if (Authenticated || mAuthenticating) {
        Debug.LogWarning("Ignoring repeated call to Authenticate().");
        return;
    }


    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        .EnableSavedGames()
            .Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);

    // Activate the Play Games platform. This will make it the default
    // implementation of Social.Active
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    // Set the default leaderboard for the leaderboards UI
    ((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).SetDefaultLeaderboardForUI(leaderboardID_android);



    // Sign in to Google Play Games
    mAuthenticating = true;
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        mAuthenticating = false;
        if (success) {

            UnityAnalytics.CustomEvent("Auth Completed", new Dictionary<string, object>
                                       {
                { "isAuthDone", true }
            });

            if(showScores){

                Social.Active.ShowLeaderboardUI();
                Debug.Log("should show leaderborad");
            }
            // if we signed in successfully, load data from cloud
            Debug.Log("Login successful!");
        } else {
            // no need to show error message (error messages are shown automatically
            // by plugin)
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to sign in with Google Play Games.");

            UnityAnalytics.CustomEvent("Auth Failed", new Dictionary<string, object>
                                       {
                { "isAuthDone", false }
            });

        }
    });
}
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    if (Authenticated) {
        showScores = false;
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderboardID_android);
        Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
        Debug.Log("should show leaderborad");

        UnityAnalytics.CustomEvent("Authenticated and show android leaderboard", new Dictionary<string, object>
                                   {
            { "isShowing", true }
        });

    }else{
        showScores = true;
        Authenticate();
    }
    #endif
```

Next, i release the alpha and check on android devices - i get a screen saying connecting to google play games...connects processes and then goes off the screen.
It seems like it authenticates and goes off. But doesn't displays leaderboard for some reason. I am not able to understand why its happening and what's missing.

In my unity analytics, only once scores aren't loaded and i played it 20-30 times :
[image]

In my Developer console, Number of scores is empty :

[image]

Can anybody pls help in this, i can provide more details to people who can help / want to help....Thanks...

Comment: What's this line?

PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new `enter code here`PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()

Comment: I have edited that. I was posting mistake here..

Comment: Getting the same error here. Did you find a solution @Sumitiscreative ?

Comment: The problem was in configuration. There is a series in which all the tasks should be done and everything needs to be done first in testing phase in play store console. Don't publish anything until you have tested it.  make sure about bundle id is same. There is a toggle on/off in leaderboard, which can't be changed once published.

Comment: I wasn't ab;le to correct the problem, so i went ahead and created everything from scratch and it worked.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!, Thanks @Sumitiscreative, I created everything from scratch(new Game on Play developer console and Project) and now it works fine. When configuring the game in the console, i made sure to not activate the Anti-Piracy feature too, maybe that was the problem in may case in the first attempt.

Comment: Yes there are certain options in toggle, which if we make it YES and publish then it doesn't allows to change it. Whereas we undergo each and every step and find that we have done correct.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Proguard for Minify > Release
and Copy the content  into Assets/Plugins/Android/proguard-user.txt

```
-keep class com.google.unity.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.event.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.stats.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.video.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.signin.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamic.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.tasks.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.security.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.base.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.actions.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.games.bridge.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.quest.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.nearby.** { *; }
```

It's work for me.