# Unity Game , Leaderboard is working in Debug Mode but Not working in release build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console, leaderboard

I have implemented a game in unity in which i have used Google Play Games to Show and Post the score in the leaderboard and that is working perfectly fine in the debug mode but it is not Getting any thing on the click of the Show Leaderboard button.

Can anyone help me with this ?!

i tried to change the SHA-1 fingerprint to App Signing Fingerprint in OAuth Credential, still it is not showing any update on the released APK.

Comment: Use Proguard-user.txt
[Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77161061/5488679)